# What’s the source of davening twords the wall?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, talmud-gemara, torah-study, synagogue

BH

What’s the source or is there a source of davening facing towards the wall and not if someone is in front of you? Is the optimum way to daven facing right towards the wall and not behind someone davening? Or both ok and equal?

Comment: See King 2:20:2

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.90.21